# Weird behaviour of the F11 key in macbook air m1

Tags: mac, function-keys

hey i just bought a new m1 macbook air and when i was checking the keys in a online keyboard checker i couldnt just get my F11 key detected while pressing (fn+F11) whereas all other keys got detected and when i used this F11 key at the time when i was not in full screen on a web browser it just showed me the the desktop and did the work it is supposed to do my doubt is:-
1)Does this F11 key not work while in full screen to show desktop(it works for sound flawlessly
every-time)
2) Why did the keyboard checker not identify the key when i pressed it(i tried multiple websites of keyboard checking)

---

hey i just disabled the System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control —> deselect F11 and detected the key can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in fullscreen because in fullscreen there is only one window to show.
Its purpose isn't to show you the desktop, it's to show you all available windows in that Space.